# Processing a HTML email template file and php

Tags: php, email

I created a html email `welcome.tpl` what php mail method do I have to use in order to send out that file as the body of the message? prior to this I've been using and including the html and text in variables

```
$text_content.= "\r\n";
$text_content.= "--------------------------------\r\n";
$html_content.= "</body></html>";

$mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";

$body = "--$mime_boundary\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body.= $text_content;
$body.= "\n\n";

$body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body.= $html_content;
$body.= "\n\n";
$body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";

$headers.= 'From: So <support@sos.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers.= "X-Sender-IP: $_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]\r\n";
$headers.= 'Date: '.date('n/d/Y g:i A')."\r\n";
$headers.= 'Reply-To: So <support@sos.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
```

should i be using something like `$body = file_get_contents();` and is `mail();` the best method?

Comment: Which templating library are you using? Can you show important parts of welcome.tpl and mail function?

Comment: @Jomoos i've added snippets of my current mail() function... as for the welcome.tpl its just basic html using the required email only acceptable html/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code :

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

and you can also include that
// More headers

```
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

and use

```
$body = file_get_contents();
```

and send the mail by mail function:

```
mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following:

You are using a .tpl extension on your template, so I'm assuming you are running Smarty as a template engine?

If not, then you can simply use file_get_contents();

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.tpl');
$template = str_replace('{name}', 'Sean Nieuwoudt', $template);
$template = str_replace('{email}', 'me@me.com', $template);
...
etc
```

The simply use the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send off the email.

The alternative and somewhat more reliable way would be to use something like [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com/) to send emails. It guarantee's delivery where as mail() might end up in the receivers spam folder (especially if running on a shared hosting environment).

With postmark, you can do something like this:

```
Mail_Postmark::compose()
    ->addTo('jane@smith.com', 'Jane Smith')
    ->subject('Subject')
    ->messagePlain($template)
    ->send();
```

Take a look at some of the freely available PHP-Postmark classes http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-libs.html#php-5